# ObjectMapper: Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1.2:

Tags: swift, build, objectmapper, carthage

I am facing this issue on Xcode 9.4.1
I tried with

```
github "Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper" ~> 3.1.0 //(tried with 3.3.0)
```

but this error.

> Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1.2 comes every-time.

I tried below things:

- Deleting the .resolved file
- Deleted the build and checkout folder
- Deleted the framework folder from builds inside cathage

tried with carthage bootstrap --platform iOS.

Updated: Below error keep on coming.

> Build Failed  Task failed with exit code 65:  /usr/bin/xcrun
>   xcodebuild -workspace
>   /Users/xx/Documents/tal1.14.1/Carthage/Checkouts/mixpanel-swift/MixpanelDemo/MixpanelDemo.xcworkspace
>   -scheme Mixpanel -configuration Release -derivedDataPath /Users/xx/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/DerivedData/9.4.1_9F2000/mixpanel-swift/v2.5.4
>   -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CARTHAGE=YES archive -archivePath
>   /var/folders/82/_m5xwhxx4795wyxlhtw40ch509_hqq/T/mixpanel-swift
>   SKIP_INSTALL=YES GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO
>   CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=NO (launched in
>   /Users/xx/Documents/tal1.14.1/Carthage/Checkouts/mixpanel-swift)
>
> This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile. Please
>   check the xcodebuild log for more details:
>   /var/folders/82/_m5xwhxx4795wyxlhtw40ch509_hqq/T/carthage-xcodebuild.2MxUDl.log
>   BLDM3295-MAC:tal xx$

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `carthage bootstrap --no-use-binaries` to make Carthage compile the frameworks locally, using the Swift 4.2 compiler that your project uses.

Comment: Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1.2: /Users/**/Documents/***/ObjectMapper.framework/Modules/ObjectMapper.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule Still same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To fix what I did, I was having success build in Jenkins Server I kept the the same version and copied the build project and framework for the same. then run

```
carthage bootstrap platform iOS
```

I know this something hack, but this is how I am able to solve.